# Can't get css tabular data to have a frozen first column

Tags: css

I'm trying to set up an html page using css.  I have tabular data that needs t o have a frozen header and first column.  I tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody').scroll(function(e) { //detect a scroll event on the tbody
   /*
    Setting the thead left value to the negative valule of tbody.scrollLeft will make it track the movement
    of the tbody element. Setting an elements left value to that of the tbody.scrollLeft left makes it maintain    it's relative position at the left of the table.    
    */
    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the thead relative to the body scrolling
    $('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first cell of the header
    $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first column of tdbody
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/*thead*/
thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
  width: 700px;
  overflow: visible;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

thead th:nth-child(1) {/*first cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the first cell in the header from the header*/
  background-color: #88b;
}


/*tbody*/
tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the tbody from the header*/
  width: 700px;
  height: 239px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: #bbc;
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  /*the first cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the first column from the tbody*/
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #99a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Town</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Profession</th>
        <th>Anual Income</th>
        <th>Matital Status</th>
        <th>Children</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Smith</td>
        <td>Macelsfield</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>Brewer</td>
        <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenny Jones</td>
        <td>Threlkeld</td>
        <td>Cumbria</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Shepherdess</td>
        <td>£28,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter Frampton</td>
        <td>Avebury</td>
        <td>Wiltshire</td>
        <td>57</td>
        <td>Musician</td>
        <td>£124,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Simon King</td>
        <td>Malvern</td>
        <td>Worchestershire</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>Naturalist</td>
        <td>£65,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lucy Diamond</td>
        <td>St Albans</td>
        <td>Hertfordshire</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>Pharmasist</td>
        <td>Retired</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Austin Stevenson</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>Lothian </td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>Vigilante</td>
        <td>£86,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wilma Rubble</td>
        <td>Bedford</td>
        <td>Bedfordshire</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>Housewife</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kat Dibble</td>
        <td>Manhattan</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>Policewoman</td>
        <td>$36,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Henry Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Lincolnshire</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Landowner</td>
        <td>Lots</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alan Brisingamen</td>
        <td>Alderley</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>352</td>
        <td>Arcanist</td>
        <td>A pile of gems</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

It does what I want.  I tried copying this example to my own fiddle page and running it, but instead of having a frozen first column, everything scrolled. Strangely enough, the first row remained frozen like I want.   I can't find a difference in what I did ? Anyone have any idea?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't use a jQuery. In the example jQuery is included as an external resource (in the left column) and the first column is staying fixed by this jQuery code:

```
$('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the thead relative to the body scrolling
$('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first cell of the header
$('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first column of tdbody
```

So you should add jQuery cdn link in your document:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js

**UPD:** the problem is the order in which scripts are running. First should be included cdn link of jQuery and after it should be running the actual code.

Comment: Thank you.  I added in the jQuery.  And it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Lisa I just tried your code in the local file and it works. It's important in which order you run your scripts. First (inside `<head>` tags) should run jQuery cdn link. After it should run jQuery script with the code. Try to replace the order, because right now your script with code can't see jQuery, because it run in the wrong order.